# Front to Back : how to pass a bean with a List attribute?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I try to test my web app application by passing a bean between my Back (Spring MVC) and my Front (Angular)

This is the Bean :

```
import java.util.List;

// liste des conférences choisies par un candidat
public class PartListFormDTO {

  private ParticipantDTO participant;
  private List<FormationDTO> listForm;

  public ParticipantDTO getParticipant() {
    return participant;
 }
 public void setParticipant(ParticipantDTO participant) {
    this.participant = participant;
 }
 public List<FormationDTO> getListForm() {
    return listForm;
 }
 public void setListForm(List<FormationDTO> listForm) {
    this.listForm = listForm;
 }
}
```

this is the controller:

```
   // formation List
  @RequestMapping(value = "/init", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public PartListFormDTO init() {
    return service.init();  
  }
```

init() sends correctely the bean to the front.
Chrome console :

```
 Object {participant: Object, listForm: Array[2]}
     listForm: Array[2]
        0: Object
        1: Object
     participant: Object
```

In my Front, i send back it immediatelly to test.

This is the controller :

```
    // formation book
@RequestMapping(value="/book", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public StatusResponse book(PartListFormDTO partListFormDTO) {
    return null;
    // return service.book(partListFormDTO);
}
```

request parameter in Angular Service :

```
 $http({
            headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'},
            //headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json;odata=verbose'},
            //headers:{'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            //        'Content-Type':'application/json; multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8'},
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            params: data
        })
            .success( function(data, status, headers, config) {
                defData.$resolve(data);
                $log.info(data);
            })
```

Now, you must know that i have other methods in my controller who works fine. If i send a bean without List attribute, it works !!
 but a bean with a list like mine, it doesn't work

```
public class PartListFormDTO {

  private ParticipantDTO participant;
  private List<FormationDTO> listForm;
   .....
```

How can i pass it ?

Comment: what error or exception are you facing?

Comment: are you sure you can pass a plain FormationDTO object back? Maybe it is not serialized correctly and then the List is not either.